# How to enable DNS over TLS using custom DNS server?

Tags: network, dns, profile-manager

I want to enable DNS over TLS for my MacOS using custom DNS server.

I am building my custom DNS infrastructure and I have set up an Unbound DNS server on a local network. For now DNS resolution flow looks like this:

- Mac sends DNS request over port 53 to local Unbound server in plaintext.
- Unbound server forwards this request over port 853 using DoT.

As you can see, between my MacOS and Unbound server traffic is transferred as a plaintext, and I want to prevent. From what I have found, if you want to enable DoT for your Mac you need to download and install profile. For example, [this is how Quad9 does this](https://support.quad9.net/hc/en-us/articles/4814293189773-Setup-MacOS-and-DNS-over-HTTPS-or-DNS-over-TLS).

Also, I have found [this page](https://simpledns.plus/apple-dot-doh), where you can generate this profile, but I doubt that this is going to work because I doesn't set certificate here.

So, I need to generate this profile, using Apple Configurator, I guess, but it's still a little confusing.

If someone has ever done this before, has step-by-step instruction and can share one or can clarify if I'm wrong somewhere, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance!